# No response error in the Browser, what can it be?

Tags: php, browser, client

I am getting a no response error in the browser.

I don't have any error in any log: apache, php...
In the dev environment everything goes fine.
The request is taking more than 180 seconds though.

Could it be the use of Ajax a solution? Considering that it takes that long, it might be a cleaner approach. Isn't it?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to increase the timeout, I'd say. Take a look at you php settings!

Comment: What are those heavy calculations? Do they all have to be done in one run, or can they be split into smaller pieces? Can partial results be sent to the browser in multiple steps?

Comment: the timeout solution doesn't work, because is the browser who cuts the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to use the AJAX method. First load the page you want the solution to appear. Then send the request asynchronously,

```
$(document).ready(function){
  $.ajax({
    url: "getAnswer.php",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function(data) {
     showAnswer(data);
  });
)};
```

And define the `showAnswer` function in the jS. Some fadeIn etc.

But I am a bit puzzled by the heavy calculation you need to run on the server. Remember, you may run into scalability issues if this is a professional deployment.

Comment: It's in an intranet and all the figures are needed... I guess the best solution is to load the page and do a background call, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. In this way, users won't be seeing a loading browser page for a long time and you have the scope for some loading animations on the results page.